# Java trouble inputting values into a 2d Array

Tags: java, arrays

I have this problem, I have to model a pipe with 1's and zeroes, the zeroes surround the pipe and the 1's are the pipe itself

I am doing this using a 2D array, My code is as follows

```
for(int i = 0; i < x2; i++) { //x1 = 10, x2 = 20
        for(int j = 0; j < x2; j++) {
            if(i >= x2 - (x1+x2)/2 && j <= (x1+x2)/2) {
                pipeArray[i][j] = 1;
            } else {
                pipeArray[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

My output looks like

```
 00000000000000000000
 00000000000000000000
 00000000000000000000
 00000000000000000000
 00000000000000000000
 11111111111111110000
 11111111111111110000
 11111111111111110000
 11111111111111110000
 11111111111111110000
 11111111111111110000
 11111111111111110000
 11111111111111110000
 11111111111111110000
 11111111111111110000
 11111111111111110000
 11111111111111110000
 11111111111111110000
 11111111111111110000
 11111111111111110000
```

And it needs to look like

```
 00000000000000000000
 00000000000000000000
 00000000000000000000
 00000000000000000000
 00000000000000000000
 00000111111111100000
 00000111111111100000
 00000111111111100000
 00000111111111100000
 00000111111111100000
 00000111111111100000
 00000111111111100000
 00000111111111100000
 00000111111111100000
 00000111111111100000
 00000000000000000000
 00000000000000000000
 00000000000000000000
 00000000000000000000
 00000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for(int i=0;i<x2;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<x2;j++){
        if(i > x2 - (x1+x2)/2 && j <= (x1+x2)/2 && i<=(x1+x2)/2 && j>(x2-(x1+x2)/2) {
            pipeArray[i][j] = 1;
        } else {
            pipeArray[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem was that you were only checking if it was lower or higher than one side. You didn't check if it was higher or lower than the other side, to see if it was in between both.

Comment: I think you need to swap the places of `1` and `0`.

Comment: @Gendarme are you sure?

Comment: I am pretty sure you will have 0's in the middle surrounded by a lot of 1's with your code, instead of the other way around.

Comment: @Gendarme I don't see how my answer is any different from your answer, but that could be me...

Comment: The conditions are different. You're checking when the coordinates are on the border; I am checking when they are in the middle. In other words, where you have `<=` I have `>`, and where you have `>=` I have `<=`. In the moment of writing this, I notice that you need to change `>=` to `>` as well.

Comment: @Gendarme That is actually true ;)

Comment: I'm sorry. I just noticed that you wrote `x1+x2` and not `x2-x1` like I have done. The `1` and `0` are correctly placed. You just need to change `>=` to `>` and it's good.

Comment: `<=` was correct. It shouldn't be `<`. Only `>=` was incorrect.

Comment: @Gendarme Yeah I noticed just now, it's late(12PM) and as I'm 14 years old I should be asleep really :/

Answer (score 0):

It's your conditional `i >= x2 - (x1+x2)/2 && j <= (x1+x2)/2`.  You are saying "if the row is greater than five and the column is less than 15 then put a 1".  What you need to say is "if the row is greater than five and less than 15 and if the column is greater than 5 and less than 15".

Answer (score 0):

You are missing two conditions : j >= (x2 - (x1+x2)/2) to restrict the 1s from the left. You have a condition for the right side. also i <= (x1+x2)/2 to restrict from the bottom.

```
for(int i = 0; i < x2; i++) { //x1 = 10, x2 = 20
    for(int j = 0; j < x2; j++) {
        if(i >= x2 - (x1+x2)/2 && i <= (x1 + x2)/2 && j <= (x1+x2)/2 && j >= (x1 - (x1+x2)/2)) {
            pipeArray[i][j] = 1;
        } else {
            pipeArray[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really explained the rule properly, but regarding the wanted output I assume that you want a `x2`x`x2` grid where the 1's are a `x1`x`x1`-block in the middle surrounded by 0's. In other words:

- If the coordinates `i` and `j` **are both** larger than `(x2-x1)/2` but smaller than or equal to `x2-(x2-x1)/2`, have a 1; otherwise have a 0.

It would be translated to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < x2; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < x2; j++) {
        if(i > (x2-x1)/2 && j > (x2-x1)/2 && i <= x2-(x2-x1)/2 && j <= x2-(x2-x1)/2) {
            pipeArray[i][j] = 1;
        } else {
            pipeArray[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems: First, the second condition has to be added, the second is that there are only 4 row/cols of 0 at the end, so you still to subtract, for example with `(x1+x2-1)/2`

```
    for(int i = 0; i < x2; i++) { //x1 = 10, x2 = 20
        for(int j = 0; j < x2; j++) {
            if(i >= x2 - (x1+x2)/2 && j <= (x1+x2-1)/2 && j >= x2 - (x1+x2)/2 && i <= (x1+x2-1)/2) {
                pipeArray[i][j] = 1;
            } else {
                pipeArray[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For any pipe:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int map[][] = new int[n][n];

    int x = n/2;
    int xx = x/2;
    int odd = n%2;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++) {
            if((i >= x - xx && i < x + xx + odd) && (j >= x - xx && j < x + xx + odd)) map[i][j] = 1;
            else map[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++) {
            System.out.print(map[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```